# Installing BackendLess via CocoaPods generates multiple build errors

Tags: ios, backendless

I am replacing Parse with BackendLess on an iPhone app and when I install it via CocoaPods, I get 10 "no member named 'xxx' in the global namespace" errors in another library which is using C++ functions.

I am using Xcode 7.2 building for iOS 9.2. When I remove Backendless-ios-SDK from the Podfile and run 'pod install' again, all the errors disappear and all is well. Is there something that I can do without rewriting C++ code? Thank you

Comment: Which Cocoapod? There are at least 3: https://cocoapods.org/?q=backendless. Also, is your project Swift or Obj-C?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. CocoaPod: 'Backendless-ios-SDK' using ObjC

Comment: Remove your derived data, also `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`. If that doesn't do it, post exact errors.

Comment: I tried the above to no avail. Here is a link of a screenshot of the errors: <https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/258556/12730734/2107fec8-c8e2-11e5-96fe-0dd3e63ca349.png>

Comment: can't access URL. Post in plain text in the post.

Comment: Thank you SwiftArchitect - I wound up getting help from the developers on GitHub <https://github.com/Backendless/ios-SDK/issues/4> - I had to install it manually for now until they find a solution which will take some time.